# Category link redirect to custom template page instead of index.php?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, templates, redirect, template-redirect

I want to make template page for my custom taxonomy.

I have custom taxonomy categories listed as navigation links. It's the country list (China, Slovenia, Serbia...). Every of this categories has cities as their subcategories (Belgrade, Honk Kong...).

When i click on the e.g. **China** i get redirected to index.php Wordpress template file where there is some loop and scripts that show content. That is working great, but i don't want that :)

I want, when i click on the category, to be **redirected on my custom template page** in which i would make some scripts that would display cities list for that country and when i click on the city i would go to index.php template and show the posts for that city!

I hope you understand whatr i'm looking for! Please help!

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Answer (score 1):

Your question implies that `index.php` is a page to be redirected to, it isn't, it's purely a template file. It implies that `single.php` being loaded is what makes a page singular, or that loading the `page.php` template will give you a page, when it's actually the other way around.

I **strongly** recommend reading about [the template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), it should answer your question, and make a few things about WordPress chooses a template file to load in your theme make a lot more sense.

Specifically WordPress:

- Uses rewrite rules to match the URL to a set of query variables to pass into a database query
- Passes those through the `pre_get_posts` filter then makes the query to grab posts
- Uses those query variables to choose a template

E.g. if the `s` query var is present, then `is_search()` will return true, and WordPress will look for a `search.php` theme template to load. If it doesn't exist, it loads the fallback, `archive.php`, and if that doesn't exist it loads the final fallback `index.php`.

In your custom taxonomy case it will load these files in this order until it finds one:

- `taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php`
- `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php`
- `taxonomy.php`
- `archive.php`
- if paged=true: `paged.php`
- `index.php`

Were $taxonomy is the internal name of your taxonomy ( as used in `register_taxonomy` ), and `$term` is the ID of the taxonomy term.

#### Further Reading

- [WordPress Developer Hub- Template Hierarchy and loading](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)
- [WP Hierarchy, interactive graph](http://wphierarchy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myTemplateSelect() {
    if (is_category() ) {

            load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/nameoftemplate.php');
            exit;

    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'myTemplateSelect');
```

add this in your functions.php.

replace your template path with  `TEMPLATEPATH . '/nameoftemplate.php`

Comment: It isn't regular category, as i explained above. It's custom taxonomy, and if I manage to redirect with this function it will also redirect on template when i click on the subcategory and i don't want that! I want this redirection just for first level

Comment: thanks for this solution, but it is bad practice, to use `template_redirect` for includes. cause after that hook some other filters are running, and they might break the site, if you use your solution. you can run your function with the `template_include` hook, to change the template.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add [template files](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) to your theme as [pr1nc3](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/36972/pr1nc3) linked to.

WordPress will automatically load the appropriate file when the taxonomy term is requested.